# Programming Chinese Arduinos

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, atmega328

I have an authentic Arduino UNO, but I didn't want to pay full price for a new one to build semi perminate projects, so I bought a few ATMEGA328P-PU chips off of AliExpress:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1pcs-lot-ATMEGA328P-PU-CHIP-ATMEGA328-Microcontroller-MCU-AVR-32K-20MHz-FLASH-DIP-28/32346944696.html

But when I try to use Arduino IDE to upload the sketch to the new chips, I get these errors:

> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>   avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00

It happens 10 times and quits.

It works fine when I put the original chip back in.

If anyone has any experience with this I'd be very grateful!

**EDIT:**

Trying the burn bootloader steps, and I'm getting a new error.

Steps I took:

I'm doing the 8MHz option, and so I downloaded the breadboard-1-6-x.zip file. (I'm using Arduino IDE 1.6.5 on Mac).

I uploaded the ArduinoISP example to my working chip, then wired it up to the breadboard as per the picture.

I switched the programmer to Arduino as ISP and set the board to ATMEGA328 on breadboard (8MHz clock)

I went to tools>burn bootloader, and got this error:

> Arduino: 1.6.5 (Mac OS X), Board: "ATmega328 on a breadboard (8 MHz
>   internal clock)"
>
> /Users/andy/Desktop/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude
>   -C/Users/andy/Desktop/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf
>   -v -patmega328p -cstk500v1 -P/dev/cu.usbmodem411 -b19200 -e -Ulock:w:0x3F:m -Uefuse:w:0x05:m -Uhfuse:w:0xDA:m -Ulfuse:w:0xE2:m
>
> avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Apr 14 2015 at 16:30:25
>            Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
>            Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch
>
> ```
>      System wide configuration file is "/Users/andy/Desktop/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
>      User configuration file is "/Users/andy/.avrduderc"
>      User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping
>
>      Using Port                    : /dev/cu.usbmodem411
>      Using Programmer              : stk500v1
>      Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200 avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x15
>      AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
>      Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
>      PAGEL                         : PD7
>      BS2                           : PC2
>      RESET disposition             : dedicated
>      RETRY pulse                   : SCK
>      serial program mode           : yes
>      parallel program mode         : yes
>      Timeout                       : 200
>      StabDelay                     : 100
>      CmdexeDelay                   : 25
>      SyncLoops                     : 32
>      ByteDelay                     : 0
>      PollIndex                     : 3
>      PollValue                     : 0x53
>      Memory Detail                 :
>
>                               Block Poll               Page                       Polled
>        Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
>        ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
>        eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
>        flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
>        lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
>        hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
>        efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
>        lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
>        calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
>        signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
>
>      Programmer Type : STK500
>      Description     : Atmel STK500 Version 1.x firmware
> ```
>
> avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x14
>
> avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x02
>
> avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x10
>            Hardware Version: -1543397124
>            Firmware Version: 2165568.-1543397124
>            Topcard         : STK502
>            Vtarget         : 1.8 V
>            Varef           : 0.0 V
>            Oscillator      : Off
>            SCK period      : 0.1 us
>
> avrdude: stk500_initialize(): (b) protocol error, expect=0x10,
>   resp=0x01 avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
>            Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
>            this check.
>
> avrdude: stk500_disable(): protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x10
>
> avrdude done.  Thank you.
>
> Problem uploading to board.  See
>   http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.

Making a little progress at least...

**Solution:**

I was using this layout:

[image]

Since that was failing I decided to try using the nano that I got at the same time, and after a lot of research I found this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94KCYqS3--A

I jumpered the pins shown at the 1:30 mark to the ICSP port, **and tried burning the bootloader twice per chip, and on the second try it worked! Don't know why it had to be tried twice.**

I may go back to trying the breadboard method, just to see if it works if I try burning it twice.

Comment: Part of an authentic Arduino is a preexisting bootloader on the chip.

Comment: You need a Chinese programmer as well, since the Chinese chips don't understand our language. I've had luck with the avr USB/ASP or USB/isp series. http://r.ebay.com/lALcjc

Comment: ^ True solution, but not right explanation, Ben Heck covers the difference very well in the beginning of this: "make an avr development board" video (https://youtu.be/ncobWc61wL4)

Comment: How is it connected? And you can add -F to the avrdude command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because these are unprogrammed chips, meaning they haven't had a bootloader programmed into them yet. [Here is a tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard) for using your Arduino board to program a bootloader into them (there are many such tutorials available).

It only needs to be done once per chip so it will be worth your while to program all of them, once you have set up to do one. This is a very economical way to build "home-brew-duinos".

Comment: I don't have the crystal, so I'll have to order some I suppose... I did see in [this Instructible](https://www.instructables.com/id/Atmega-Standalone-Running-without-crystal-oscillat/) that you can run at least some of them without the crystal. However, I also got an Arduino Nano that works... Could I put the 328P-PU into the UNO, and then program it with the Nano?

Comment: @AndyD273: Sure, just use the ISP connection near the main MCU, not the ISP connection near the USB connector.

Comment: you can run them at 8mhz w/o a crystal, 16 with one.

Comment: Ok, I got it wired up using the internal 8mhz clock as in your link, but I'm getting a new error. I posted it above.